# ARC-aware UIImage from UIView

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiview, uiimage, automatic-ref-counting

My application iterates through a directory of PDF-files, draws there first page into a off-screen UIView subclass using the CGPDF API functions, which makes a UIImage available to the application. The UIView subclass simply adds the *@property (nonatomic,assign) image*, which in its setter uses the standard way to get a UIImage from a UIView, as per Apple references.

UIViewWithImage.h:

```
@interface UIViewWithImage : UIView {
    UIImage* image;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage* image;
@end
```

UIViewWithImage.m:

```
@implementation UIViewWithImage
@dynamic image;
-(UIImage*)image {

    if( [self.layer respondsToSelector:@selector(setShouldRasterize:)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( self.bounds.size, NO, self.contentScaleFactor );
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
@end
```

So far, so good. My application uses ARC (automatic reference counting) and crashes in this method, short after memory warnings are received. There is no exception thrown, instruments was not of great help as I could not observe memory accumulations. Only removing the code from the setter saves the app from crashing.

I have read a lot about bridging, which seems not applicable in my case. It seems to me that the code above allocates objects and never frees them, at least that will explain the memory warnings.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `weak` or `strong` properties, and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks Brad. You mean I should change the `@property (nonatomic,assign)` to `@property (nonatomic,strong)`?

Comment: @dev.microfunc either that or weak, it's hard to say based on the limited design points you have given us

Comment: I basically use a altered implementation of [UIImage+PDF](https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF/tree/master/UIImage+PDF) without the caching and have about 100 PDF files, which I use to create PNG files.

Comment: Then weak sounds like the right way to go. Try it, and let me know.

Comment: I already tried with `weak`, but the memory warning and following crash still happen. For a better overview I added the full code above.

Comment: It sounds like image isn't really a property here, since you're always generating it dynamically and you can't set it. So why back it with an instance variable? Why not remove the UIImage* image in the interface declaration, get rid of the property, and just implement a -(UIImage*)image method. Then declare UIImage* image locally inside  it and just return it. The autorelease mechanism should take care of memory management without you doing anything else. If, on the other hand, you are storing the value you get back in another class, make sure *that* attribute is marked as strong.

Comment: Thanks Philip. Unfortunately the given suggestion did not change the behavior.The app still crashes with same symptoms.

Comment: Just for your info: I ended up rewriting the whole code that saves a PNG file to a specified filepath at a given size from a given PDF filepath. This is now all done in one monolithic method, which means that there is no vague object responsibility-shifting happening anymore.